# Объединение 3-х ArrayList<String> в 1

Tags: java

Всех приветствую. Есть такой код:

```
final ArrayList<String> TodayArray = new ArrayList<>();
                final ArrayList<String> YesterdayArray = new ArrayList<>();
                final ArrayList<String> OnThisWeekArray = new ArrayList<>();


                TodayArray.add(0, "          Сегодня:     ");
                YesterdayArray.add(0, "          Вчера:     ");
                OnThisWeekArray.add(0, "          На этой неделе:     ");

                for (DataSnapshot chidSnap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    for (long i = 0; i<chidSnap.getChildrenCount(); i++){
                        if (chidSnap.getKey().equals(CurrentDate.get("DayOfYear"))){
                            TodayArray.add((int)i+1, ToUpper(String.valueOf(WordIndex + 1) + ". " + String.valueOf(chidSnap.child(String.valueOf(i + 1)).child("word").getValue())));
                        }else if (chidSnap.getKey().equals(yesterday)){
                            YesterdayArray.add((int)i+1, ToUpper(String.valueOf(WordIndex + 1) + ". " + String.valueOf(chidSnap.child(String.valueOf(i + 1)).child("word").getValue())));
                        }else{
                            OnThisWeekArray.add((int)i+1, ToUpper(String.valueOf(WordIndex + 1) + ". " + String.valueOf(chidSnap.child(String.valueOf(i + 1)).child("word").getValue())));
                        }
                        WordIndex++;
                    }
                }
```

Он содержит 3 массива, 1 массив - содержит слова этого дня, 2-й массив - вчерашнего дня, 3-й массив - все слова, "старше" вчерашнего дня.

Нужно объединить все эти массивы в 1 (ArrayList) - как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создать новый и addAll? например:

```
        int initialCapacity = TodayArray.size() + YesterdayArray.size() + OnThisWeekArray.size();
        List<String> all = new ArrayList<>(initialCapacity);
        all.addAll(TodayArray);
        all.addAll(YesterdayArray);
        all.addAll(OnThisWeekArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Похоже что это не массивы а списки. Объединить два списка в один можно методом

```
list1.addAll(list2);
```